# Three.js - position object at vertex of another

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an IcosahedronGeometry defined like this (with all the code about colors and non-position stuff omitted):

```
var radius = 200;
geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(radius, 2);

var materials = [
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({})
];
group1 = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geometry, materials);
group1.position.x = 0;
// rotate a bit just so it spins off-axis
group1.rotation.x = -1.87;
```

Which creates an almost spherical, many-sided shape.
I want to place little spheres at just a few of the vertices of this shape. Let's say 10 spheres. I do this by copying 10 vertices into an array, like this:

```
var vertexArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    vertexArray.push(geometry4.vertices[i])
}
```

then, I use the Vectors copied into `vertexArray` to set the positions off Sprites:

```
for (var i = 0; i < vertexArray.length; i++) {
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
    var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial(
        {
            map: loader.load('/glow.png'),
            blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
            side: THREE.BackSide
        })
    var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterial)

    sprite.position.set(vertexArray[i].x, vertexArray[i].y, vertexArray[i].z)
    // do i need rotate these by the same amount?
    sprite.rotation.x = -1.87
    scene.add(sprite)
}
```

This all works fine, except that the Sprites don't line up with the actual vertices on the Icosahedron, they just sit randomly (seemingly) somewhere on the faces. Occasionally a Sprite will sit exactly on a vertex.

Am I copying the vertices wrong, or missing a step in here?

Comment: Try `group1.add( sprite )`, instead. Do not set `sprite.rotation`.

Comment: Wow that was it, thank you. So can you `add` any object within a scene to any other within that same scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an object as a child of a parent object, and the child object will rotate with the parent.

Use this pattern, instead:

```
var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial );

sprite.position.copy( vertexArray[i] );

group1.add( sprite );
```

three.js r.76